# Firefox 301 redirect for non-URL image src. Bug or feature?

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, redirect, src

You can do the trick like so:

1. Open any website **without SSL** in Firefox, then open console
2. Execute this code: `var img = new Image(); img.src = 'something';`
3. You'll get 301 redirect at 'http://example.com/something' (not just image URL, **but document URL will be changed**).

So, is it a bug or feature?

P.S. instead of example.com can be any website.

Comment: that's how images or any url like ajax or script tag src work, if you don't specify the `http://domain.com` the url will be local based on the site you're on.

Comment: You are also right, but the question is not about that.

Comment: I don't get any redirect, just 404.

Comment: Exactly, you'll get 404 immediately after 301 redirect, it's expected behavior.

Comment: I don't get redirect just `https://example.com/something` that return 404.

Comment: Okey. So, the question is why replacing the `img.src` by `"whatever, but non-valid URL"` leads to replacing URL of document (only in Firefox, and only at the non-SSL websites)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go through my extensions and disable some "search me" malware add-on.  Try disabling your add-ons one by one to find if one of them is the culprit

Comment: Truly, there is malware extension Searchme 2.8. Removing it fixes my issues. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried something like 'http://example.com'? Because 'example.com' could also be an folder on your server or client

Comment: You are right, but that's not important at this case.

Comment: The point is that if src attribute is not a valid URL — firefox will do 301 redirect for whole document (not just for image). I've tried on 42 version of Firefox.